# tablet effect on page

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem to create scroll effect like a tablet.

Here is my simple code.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxy0cyfy/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="blank"></div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis officia voluptas distinctio dolore quod.   Minima delectus nisi sapiente nostrum, illum ea explicabo quae veritatis accusamus earum sequi ipsa. Aspernatur, rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis officia voluptas distinctio dolore quod.   Minima delectus nisi sapiente nostrum, illum ea explicabo quae veritatis accusamus earum sequi ipsa. Aspernatur, rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis officia voluptas distinctio dolore quod.   Minima delectus nisi sapiente nostrum, illum ea explicabo quae veritatis accusamus earum sequi ipsa. Aspernatur, rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis officia voluptas distinctio dolore quod.   Minima delectus nisi sapiente nostrum, illum ea explicabo quae veritatis accusamus earum sequi ipsa. Aspernatur, rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis officia voluptas distinctio dolore quod.   Minima delectus nisi sapiente nostrum, illum ea explicabo quae veritatis accusamus earum sequi ipsa. Aspernatur, rerum!</p>    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blank big"></div>
```

CSS

```
.blank{
  height: 400px;
  &.big{
    height: 800px;
  }
}
.outer{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px -50px);
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

When the page is scrolled, the box (.outer) appears, and when it is in the middle of the screen, I want the page to stop and only the second box (.inner) has been scrolled until the content ends (the best option will be witchout second scrollbar). Then the page should continue to scroll normally.

Any1 can help me?